# Retornar una vista u otra basándose en un input ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo un problema, necesito retornar una vista u otra basándome en un valor que ingrese el usuario, es por si un registro existe o no en una base de datos.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string documento)
    {
        ExisteEmpleado(ViewBag.Documento = documento);
        return View();
    }

    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public ActionResult ExisteEmpleado(string documento)
    {
        if (db.Empleado.Any(t => t.documento == documento))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("DetallesNomina");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("NoEncontrado");
        }
    }

    public ActionResult DetallesNomina(string documento)
    {
        NominaCalculos nomina = new NominaCalculos();
        //hacer inner join para consultar el salario basandose en el cargo del empleado
        //con el documento recibido y llenar los viewbag de abajo
        nomina.GenerarNomina(1000000, 30);
        ViewBag.Documento = "";
        ViewBag.NombreCompleto = "";
        ViewBag.Cargo = "";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult NoEncontrado()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Cuando lo hago así lo único que pasa es que la vista "Index" se refresca y ya. Pero no redirecciona. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por parte.
Primero desde el html debes hacer post

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ExisteEmpleado", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input type="text" id="documento" name="documento" />//Declaras el textbox con el nombre de parametro en el controller
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar"  />
        @ViewBag.Mensaje;
    }
```

Segundo, desde el codebehind recibiras el documento

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()//Cuando cargue por primera vez la página entrara aquí
    {
        return View();
    }



    public ActionResult ExisteEmpleado(string documento)//cuando haces post desde el submit entra aquí, con el documento.
        {
//Aqui debes poner el código que necesitas para buscar, espero que lo realices en otra clase para no mezclar.
            Empleado e = new Empleado();//Clase dummy para el ejemplo
            e.Documento = "123456";
            e.ID = 1;
            e.Nombre = "Nombre ppp";

            if (e.Documento == documento)//validar si el documento es igual
                return View("ExisteEmpleado", e);//solicitar cargar la página pasando el modelo, en este caso es empleado.
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Mensaje = "No Existe";
                return View("Index");//si no existe puedes cargar el index y pasar una variable viebag para que indique que no se encontró el registro.
            }
        }
    }
```

Tercero, en la página ExisteEmpleado debes tiparla

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Empleado//tipando la página

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ExisteEmpleado";//titulo
}

<h2>ExisteEmpleado</h2>
@Model.Documento//Mostramos los datos del modelo

@Model.Nombre

@Model.ID
```

Espero que te haya quedado un poco más claro, saludos.
Trata de utilizar el modelo para los datos y otra clase para los cálculos, y el controller solo para mostrar las vistas.